# Update CREATED BY Col in image history command during commit

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

If I build the image using `docker build .` with the below Dockerfile content, I see the label getting listed in the `CREATED BY` column when I run `docker history <image_id>`.

```
IMAGE          CREATED          CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT

7365e50be12b   12 minutes ago   LABEL version=0.1                               0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0

missing      12 minutes ago   CMD ["redis-server"]                            0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0

missing      12 minutes ago   LABEL version=0.0                               0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0

missing      12 minutes ago   RUN /bin/sh -c apk add --update gcc # buildk…   106MB     buildkit.dockerfile.v0

missing      12 minutes ago   RUN /bin/sh -c apk add --update redis # buil…   5.65MB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0

missing      11 days ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/sh"]              0B        
missing      11 days ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:2a949686d9886ac7c…   5.54MB
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk add --update redis

RUN apk add --update gcc

CMD ["redis-server"]

LABEL version="0.1"
```

My question is: when I create a container and then run commit with `-c` as

`docker commit -c 'LABEL version="0.1"' container id`

I don't see the `LABEL` info in the `CREATED BY` column.

Is there a way to update the `CREATED BY` column during the `commit` command?

Comment: As a general rule, you should probably never use `docker commit` at all.  Do you have a specific reason to not use a Dockerfile here?

Comment: My requirement is I have StackRox scan which reads CREATED BY column for instructions. Also, I understand commit is not the recommended way but I already have commit instructions in my process and I just want to append label during commit so that they appear in CREATED BY column during image history. In my project, I am not using Dockerfile to create images, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

`Label` is supported by the docker commit but its is not something you can track with docker image history as its the snapshot of the running container.

> The `--change` option will apply Dockerfile instructions to the image that is created. Supported Dockerfile instructions: `CMD|ENTRYPOINT|ENV|EXPOSE|LABEL|ONBUILD|USER|VOLUME|WORKDIR`

[docker-commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/)

You can get the desired result from `docker inspect image`

```
docker image inspect mynew-label-image | grep version
--
    "version": "0.1"
```

Also, this is not recommended approach to managing change like this

> Generally, it is better to use Dockerfiles to manage your images in a documented and maintainable way.
> [commit-recommendation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/#description)

Comment: Truth be told, I have read everything thoroughly already. My requirement is I have StackRox scan which reads CREATED BY column for instructions. Also, I understand commit is not the recommended way but I already have `commit` instructions in my process and I just want to append label during `commit` so that they appear in CREATED BY column during image history. In my project, I am not using Dockerfile to create images, unfortunately.

Comment: so just try to replicate but it but does seems something you can get with commit, the commit is come as single layer with `bash` only, not the changes that applied

Comment: I couldn't understand the above comment. I apologize.

Comment: I mean the commit changes packed as a single docker layer with `bash` like this `a525b25a111e   5 minutes ago   /bin/sh                                         0B` so the only thing you can use is `docker inspect`